# How to deploy multiple smart contracts using hardhat-deploy

Tags: smartcontracts, ethers.js, hardhat

I have two smart contracts that I want to deploy. I want to deploy the first one, then pass the address of the first into the constructor of the second one. I am new to hardhat-deploy and keep getting caught up with this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

First create file "scripts/deploy.js".

```js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    console.log('Deploying contracts with the account: ' + deployer.address);

    // Deploy First
    const First = await ethers.getContractFactory('FirstContract');
    const first = await First.deploy();

    // Deploy Second
    const Second = await ethers.getContractFactory('SecondContract');
    const second = await Second.deploy(first.address);

    console.log( "First: " + first.address );
    console.log( "Second: " + second.address ); 
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit())
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
})
```

Then run this command.

```bash
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten
```

Comment: It works. To deploy multiple contracts, all you need is to put a loop around it.
    for(let i = 0; i < numberOfContracts; i++ ) {
        const MyNFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyNFT")
        const myNFT = await MyNFT.deploy();
    }

Answer (score 0):

The original question specifically refers to the `hardhat-deploy` NPM package (i.e. the community plugin for hardhat tooling).  On that basis the answer provided is not directly correct.

`hardhat-deploy`'s documentation is extensive and thorough. The portion relevant to the deployment of (multiple) contracts is [here](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy/tree/master#how-to-deploy-contracts)

Answer (score 0):

The hardhat deployment documentation [here](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy/tree/master#how-to-deploy-contracts) may be a little bit cryptic for newcomers. But it is very simple to deploy multiple contracts using `hardhat deploy`.

First create the deployment scripts in the `deploy` directory which is in the same level as of `contracts` directory.
You can name the deployment scripts like `01-deploy-contract-1.js`, `02-deploy-contract-2.js` etc.

A sample deploy script is as shown below.

`01-deploy-contract-1.js`

```
const { ethers, hardhat, upgrades, network } = require("hardhat");

require("dotenv").config();
async function deployFunc(hre) {
  if (process.env.DEPLOY_TOKEN_LIB.toLowerCase() === "true") {
    console.log("Deploying Contract - 1...");
    await deployContract1();
    console.log("-------------------------");
  }
}

async function deployContract1() {
  const networkName = network.name;

  let owner = ethers.getSigner();
  console.log(`Deploying to '${networkName}' as ${(await owner).address}...`);
  const contract1 = await ethers.getContractFactory("Contract1");
  lib = await contract1.deploy((await owner).address);
  await lib.deployed();
  console.log(`Token library contract deployed to ${contract1.address}`);
}

module.exports.default = deployContract1;
module.exports.tags = ["all", "tokenlibrary"];
```

Now run `npx hardhat deploy`. It will run all the deployment scripts in the `deploy` folder.

An added advantage of hardhat deployment scripts is, when you run `npx hardhat node`, it will automatically deploy all the contracts, and your local node will be ready with all the contracts ready to test.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are mostly focusing on deployment of multiple contracts. None of them actually consider parameters to be passed to the contracts during deployment.

Note that OP asks for the address of the first contract to be fed as an argument to the constructor of 2nd contract

Constructors are run only once that is during the deployment of the contract. Hence, the deployment code needs to be adjusted to accept parameters as well.

I have created 2 contracts,

- one that accepts an unsigned integer as input to its constructor
- second that accepts the address of 1st contract as input to its constructor

These contracts are deployed using 2 different methods. Note that they can be certainly and easily interchanged.
You can choose whichever one you like

```
async function main()
{
    //Deploying the first contract
    const td = await ethers.getContractFactory("testingDeploy");
    const TD = await td.deploy(2)

    console.log(`The deployment testing contract was deployed at ${TD.target}`);

    /*
      Now, another method for deploying.
      While they do the same thing, I am unsure what are the pros and cons on use of either.
    */

    //Deploying the second contract:
    const td1 = await ethers.deployContract("testingDeploy2", [TD.target]);
    await td1.waitForDeployment();

    console.log(`The second contract accepting address of 1st contract is deployed at ${td1.target}`);
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode=1;
})
```